# IPhone Resets Communication from Server

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, wireshark

I have an mp4 (h.264) file that I want to play on an IPhone (via HTTP). When the file sits on a Windows IIS server, my IPhone and IPad will play the video without any issues.

The file is here:  [test file](http://branddemo.gemini.com/html5/html5.mp4)
I will leave access to this server for a few days for testing purposes.

When the file sits on our proprietary server, my IPhone and IPad request the download, but then stops the process almost immediately. Non IOS phones and desktop browsers have no problems requesting and viewing the video from the proprietary server.  I don't believe that it has anything to do with the HTTP response headers because of the fact that non-IOS phones can play the video.

I use Wireshark to see the http/tcp requests between the IPhone and the server. I see the IPhone request the mp4 and then I see the server send a "200 OK" response and then start to send the file. Soon after the server starts to send the file, the IPhone sends a "reset" request which stops the sending of the file.

Any ideas why the IPhone would reset the communication and stop the file from being sent? I am far from a regular user of Wireshark, so hopefully, my reading of the file is correct.

Here is an image of my Wireshark capture if anyone is interested. It clearly shows the reset from the IPhone.

[Wireshark Image](http://branddemo.gemini.com/html5/IPhoneMP4.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dana

Comment: Are you using the browser? Is this a programing question? Can you please share some code? The best way to get a file to your app via http in my opinion is using AFNetworking.

Comment: I'm using Safari on the IPhone.  I type in the URL to the file on our server, but the video file does not download.  It appears that the IPhone is resetting the connection.  I have no trouble downloading an mp3 file to the IPhone from the same server.

Comment: This has been solved.  Our server did not handle HTTP requests for partial content (i.e. Range: bytes=0-999).  Range headers in incoming requests were being ignored.

We updated the server to handle these requests and IOS devices are now able to download video from our server.

See the link below for more info:

http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-latest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved.  Our server did not handle HTTP requests for partial content (i.e. Range: bytes=0-999).  Range headers in incoming requests were being ignored.

We updated the server to handle these requests and IOS devices are now able to download video from our server.

See the link below for more info:

http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-latest.html